# CakePHP - Class ** cannot be found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have a strange problem with CakePHP
CakePHP gives an error on the following line:

```
View/Designer/cards:
$this->JsBridge->set('Card.DISPLAY_TYPE_FOLDER_GREETING', Card::DISPLAY_TYPE_FOLDER_GREETING);
Class 'card' can not be found.
```

However in DesignersController I load the model Card via de following line:

```
public $uses = array('Designer', 'Card');
```

If I add the following line in the top of DesignersController

```
App::uses('Card', 'Model');
```

The page loads, but the following line does not work:

```
$this->paginate = $this->Card->getPagination($filter);
```

I have put the code for the model Card.php here : http://pastebin.com/U7zxKHCx

Can you tell me what is going wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: You're applying `App::uses` in the Controller, the error comes from a View apparently. That's a no no.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you including the `CardModel` in your Controller?

   `$uses = array('....','Card',....);`
2. Controller properties, classes attached etc. are NOT directly accessible in a View. You will need to set this constant `Card::DISPLAY_TYPE_FOLDER_GREETING` to a variable:

   `$this->set('variableName1', Card::DISPLAY_TYPE_FOLDER_GREETING);`
3. Then use it in the View:

   `$this->JsBridge->set('Card.DISPLAY_TYPE_FOLDER_GREETING', $variableName1);`